# How to know "web3.js" version?

Tags: web3js

Is there a specific command to know which version of `web3.js` has been installed on our machine ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the command:

```
Web3 = require("web3")
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

web3.version;
'1.0.0-beta.34'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reinstall web3.js with the command to check the version after reinstall. In addition, you can check in the package.json file can also see version of web3